# ROS Kinetic Installation Error on OSX Mojave

Tags: python, installation, homebrew, ros, robotics

During the process of installing ROS kinetic on my mac. I've been trying to resolve dependencies using the following commands:

```
$ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws
$ rosinstall_generator ros_comm --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall
$ wstool init -j8 src kinetic-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall

$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y # resolves dependancies
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "gtest" 

ERROR: Rosdep experienced an internal error.
Please go to the rosdep page [1] and file a bug report with the message below.
[1] : http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep

rosdep version: 0.13.0

Bad installer [homebrew]: Error while parsing brew info for 'gtest'
 * Output of `brew info gtest --json=v1`:

 * Error while parsing:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosdep2/platforms/osx.py", line 203, in is_installed
    pkg_info = json.loads(std_out)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling several things, but I'm not sure what the actual issue is and how I can fix this.

Comment: `$ brew install gtest`

Comment: Tried it and got: `Error: No available formula with the name "gtest" `

Comment: first you must prepare brew for get ros relatives.
`$ brew tap ros/deps`
http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source

Answer (score 1):

As also specified in the [guide](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source), *Google Mock* is not compatible with OS X so you should skip it adding `--skip-keys google-mock` to `rosdep install`